# How to set a loading state for react component while sorting and filtering data?

Tags: reactjs, state, loading

I am trying to implement a table and do filtering and searching of data from the table. Since the searching and sorting takes a while I would like to implement a spinner display to show that the search/filtering is running.

Below is how I have implemented the component, I call filterData/ searchData to search through the data and return the results which is passed as props to the Grid Table component and where the data is displayed.

```
 {this.state.search && this.state.filter &&
                      <GridTable  
                      results= {filterData(this.state.filter,searchData(this.state.search,this.state.Data))}
                        />}
                      { this.state.search && !this.state.filter &&
                        <GridTable 
                        results = {searchData(this.state.search,this.state.Data)}
                        />}
                      { !this.state.search && this.state.filter &&
                          <GridTable 
                          results= {filterData(this.state.filter,this.state.Data)}
                          />}
                      { !this.state.search && !this.state.filter &&
                            <GridTable  
                            results = {this.state.Data}
                            />}
```

Where should i implement a loading state and set its state? I am confused since I am directly passing the result of the search/ filter functions into the props.

Comment: The loading state would need to be set to true/false within the logic that is fetching the data... which hopefully isn't any of the functions you've referenced in your question. Filtering data shouldn't require a loading state.

Answer (score 1):

In your render method you can have one loader implemented like

```
<Loader visible={this.state.visibility}>
```

In your searchData method, you can set the visibility of this loader true in the first line and false in the last line like below

```js
searchData = () => {
  // Start the loader
  this.setState({
    visibility: true,
  });

  //  ....Your logic goes here

  // Stop the loader
  this.setState({
    visibility: false,
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried this and I get this error: "This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

Comment: Error states that you have problem in componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate and you must be doing setState in those which is not allowed

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that loading state relates to the whole `Grid` component. It is sound wisely if you manage this state in root of your module (Table/Grid).

To pass global module state, like loading state, to children components you may use React Context API or some external state management library (Redux/Effector etc.).

After that you can easily use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to show spinner while data is loading.